# I want to find short strings in new lines in an R character vector

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I read a text of a few hundred words into R (using read_file on a .txt file). Some lines of the text contain only very short segments (e.g. 'Figure 1') before a `\n`. I'd like to replace these with a blank `\n`. So, in the below, I'd like to `gsub` out the last 3 lines. I think they'll all be under ~10 words, and none will have a period `.` except possibly at the end.  All will start and end with a `\n`.

```
Some are long. They might have short segments (like the preceding sentence), but they'll all be over some length, and will almost certainly have at least 2 sentence closings (abnormally long sentences aside). Others are short, like these:

Figure 1: description
  Materials and Methods
Introduction.
```

I've tried:

```
gsub("\\n(.{90,}[\\.\\?\\:].*){2,}\\n$", "\n", string1, perl=T)
```

And the [regex works](https://regex101.com/r/aE9hC8/1)
I.e. after a newline, we want some characters (at least 50) to appear before punctuation (`.?:`), and we want that pattern to repeat at least twice before the next new line. I want to add `(?gmi)` modifiers (at least, it works in regex101 with them), but I can't find how  to add them in R.  I think with modifiers the code above works, other options (e.g. to `gsub` on `\n (text) \n\` with fewer than 90 characters and only one `':.?'` or something similar might also be interesting).

**UPDATE**
I think I can use something like: `str_replace_all(test, regex("^\\n(.{50,}[\\.\\?\\:].*){2,}\\n$", multiline = T), "\n")` with `stri_opts_regex` from `stringi` to add the options...but I'm not clear on how (or, if it'll work).

Comment: Is there a reason to not use readLines instead of read_file? You seem to want to manipulate your data line by line...

Comment: I think it was because I could get read_file to work, I just tried readLines again and I get an 'incomplete final line' error.

Comment: not very elegant... but have you try cutting the string in sections and then using `nchar` to count the number of characters? `nchar(strsplit(string1,"\n")[[1]])`. I think that will give you all the information you need to apply your criteria later.

Comment: @CarlosAlberto re: `\\n` because it's in `R` the  `\` needs escaping, hence `\\`.  I hadn't considered that (thanks!) but I'm hoping there's another way as I suspect that'll be inefficient pretty fast...

Comment: Re: "I want to add `(?gmi)` modifiers (at least, it works in regex101 with them), but I can't find how to add them in R": You just put them in the pattern. They take effect until the end of the pattern, or until the end of the enclosing `(...)`.

Comment: e.g. `gsub("(?gmi)^\\n(.{50,}[\\.\\?\\:].*){2,}\\n$", "\n", y, perl=T)` gives `Error in gsub` ... `invalid regular expression` ...

Comment: `gmi/^\\n(.{50,}[\\.\\?\\:].*){2,}$/` or with the `gmi` at the end at least parses the code (it just doesn't work how I want it to; note this /does/ work on http://regex101.com ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Carlos in the comments, I gave up on the regex and have just used a `strsplit` like

```
holding <- unlist(strsplit(y,"\n"))
holding <- lapply(holding, function (bits) ifelse(nchar(bits) < 75, "", ifelse(nchar(bits)<150, ifelse(sum(str_count(bits, "\\."),str_count(bits, "\\:"),str_count(bits, "\\?"))<3, "", bits), bits)))
holding <- holding[holding != ""]; # without elements that are empty
#recombine that back into y
y <- paste(holding, collapse = "\n")
```

Not terribly elegant but does what I want without the need for `regex`.